Pyspark - Error in writing same dataframe to multiple directories on s3
I trying to save same dataframe to two different directories.
print(out_path)
s3://.../out/2012-02/

print(curr_repo_path)
s3://.../consolidate_repo_hist/

new_consolidated_repo.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(out_path) # this code works
new_consolidated_repo.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(curr_repo_path) # this does not.

If I interchange the order, whichever write statement is executed first works, and the statement executed later fails.
Error is like below -
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o612.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted...
.
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 147 in stage 865.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 147.3 in stage 865.0 (TID 15997) (ip-10-16-0-36.us-west-2.compute.internal executor 59):
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileDownloadException: Failed to download file path: s3://.../consolidate_repo_hist/part-00385-9f605c56-0f6f-449c-b140-f1f2929d076e-c000.snappy.parquet

I do not understand why it tries to download data when I am trying to write. It does delete the existing directory before writing, however while writing it throws this error.
I think my question my be slightly related to this:
Spark Scala EMR Job fails to download file from S3
, however, I am not entirely sure.
Even if I put same directory in both the statements, 2nd statement fails.
new_consolidated_repo.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(out_path) # this code works
new_consolidated_repo.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(out_path) # this does not.

